# Flutter app crashes on Android when receiving push notifications

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification

I'm experiencing an issue with my Flutter app, which crashes on Android devices when it receives a push notification. The error message I receive is:

> D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(11789): broadcast received for message
> I/flutter (11789): onMessage: Instance of 'RemoteMessage'
> W/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> W/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> W/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->size()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> W/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> W/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> W/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->isEmpty()Z (greylist-max-o, reflection, denied)
> W/FirebaseMessaging(11789): Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
> I/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Thread[3,tid=11804,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x79d2e29c00,peer=0x13f021f8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
> I/m.starfish.ryb(11789):
> I/m.starfish.ryb(11789): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

I have already tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Ensured proper setup of push notifications in the Flutter app using firebase_messaging.
2. Checked the AndroidManifest.xml file for necessary permissions and service declarations related to push notifications.
3. Initialized the Firebase Messaging instance in the main.dart file and implemented necessary event listeners (onMessage, onResume, and onLaunch).
4. Inspected the Android native code to ensure proper handling of push notifications.
5. Examined the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file to make sure they are up-to-date and compatible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[This is output of flutter run -v](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/files/11350230/run.txt)

Despite trying these steps, the issue persists. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this problem. Please let me know if you need more information or code snippets to help diagnose the issue.